# keeping a consistant layout for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout has TextViews that need to be in a certain position on the screen in that layout. If I have a layout that displays how I want it on say a 10" tablet, how can I get it to display the same on say a phone screen and keep it relative to what it would be on the tablet?

meaning how can I get both the tablet and the phone to look exactly the same xml layout views without changing them manually? Is there an xml attribute I can use that will scale the view correctly to the device screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you:

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)